# How can assign a value that comes through the query string into a hidden mvc5 register control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The typical query string looks like this:

```
/Account/Register/?ID=1
```

and I'd like to assign this ID value of '1' to this hidden `AvatarID` control during a user registration:

```
    <div style="display:none;" class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AvatarID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AvatarID, new { @class = "form-control" })
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value can be assigned directly into the control using the query string like this:

```
Html.LabelFor(m => m.AvatarID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AvatarID, new {@Value=Request.QueryString["ID"], @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Register` action on your `AccountController`, add `ID` as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult Register(int ID)
{
    var model = new RegisterModel();
    model.AvatarID = ID;
    return View(model);
}
```

As long as you haven't changed the route config.

Comment: I was assuming your register action loads a user model as you're passing the ID into the URL and using `Html.TextBoxFor`.  If not, then just ignore that part - I'll edit it out

Comment: The ID is passed from the URL. But thanks a lot for you answer

Comment: Right... and the question was how to pass this from the url into the hidden AvatarID control, which uses a `TextBoxFor`.  If you're using MVC, the correct way to do this is via a model from your controller.